# Asmx webservice referencing issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I need to call my web service method with JavaScript in my client page. I think I am not properly referencing this correctly and would appreciate help figuring this out please.

The error message says **"CalendarHandler is not defined"**.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/CalendarHandler.cs"
  Class="CalendarHandler" %>
```

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CalendarPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="CalendarPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

      <input type="button" id="loadevents" onclick="callLoadEvents();" />
      <div id="eventresults"> </div>
      <div id="resultFailed"> </div>

      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var tasks;

            function callLoadEvents() {

                  Speak.CalendarHandler.GetEvents(GetLoadAddress_success, OnFailed); 
            }
            function GetLoadAddress_success(e) { 
                  tasks = e;
            }
            // --------------------------
            function OnFailed() { 
                  $get('resultFailed').innerHTML = "failed";
            }

      </script>
</asp:Content>



using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "Speak")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
public class CalendarHandler : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
      static IDictionary<DateTime, String> Calendarevents;//hold my events in this 

    public CalendarHandler () {
          Calendarevents = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
          Calendarevents.Add(DateTime.Now, "Going to meeting with XYZ Company");
          Calendarevents.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), "XML Class at 2pm");
          Calendarevents.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),"ASP.NET 3.5 Ajax");
          Calendarevents.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),"Pocket Guide");
          Calendarevents.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),"Grocery Shopping");

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public IDictionary<DateTime, String> GetEvents()
    {
        return Calendarevents;
    }

}
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a ScriptManager on that page's Master?

There are basically two keys to enabling the nice `Namespace.Service.Method` syntax: MicrosoftAjax.js and a service-specific JavaScript proxy.

You get MicrosoftAjax.js automatically when you have a ScriptManager anywhere on the page (or it's Master(s)).

To get the JavaScript proxy, you'll need either a ServiceReference on the ScriptManager or a JavaScript include that points to where that's generated from.  E.g.:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="/CalendarHandler.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>

<script>
  // Speak.CalendarHandler.GetEvents() will be available here.
</script>
```

All that actually does is inject the script that's available at `/CalendarHandler.asmx/js` (or /jsdebug when running in debug).  That's part of what the `ScriptService` attribute on the service enables.

So, as long as MicrosoftAjax.js is already being injected from somewhere on the page, you could also simply add a script reference to that JavaScript proxy yourself:

```
<script src="/CalendarHandler.asmx/js"></script>

<script>
  // Speak.CalendarHandler.GetEvents() will be available here.
</script>
```

---

Update:

If the service proxy generation code isn't respecting the `Namespace` parameter in your `[WebService]` attribute, can you namespace the service code with the namespace keyword instead?

```
namespace Speak
{
  [ScriptService]
  public class CalendarHandler : WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public IDictionary<DateTime, string> GetEvents()
    {
      // Etc.
    }
  }
}
```

I can confirm that this approach does affect the generated service proxy.

Comment: I removed the servicereference from the master page scriptmanager, and instead used a scriptmanagerproxy as you have above in the child page. I still have the problem of not being able to call the webservice method using the namespace I have defined for my service.

Comment: I am able to call my reference with     CalendarHandler.GetEvents(GetLoadAddress_success, OnFailed); but not Speak.CalendarHandler.GetEvents(GetLoadAddress_success, OnFailed);

Comment: Thanks. I removed the [Webservice] attribute and used the namespace parameter, and that worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You need to serialize the collection you have in your webmethod to json and have the return method to return a string (= actually is the serialized output of your collection = json).

Look at [Encosia](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/). It propably has the most thorough articles about asp.net, javascript and jquery working together.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


 JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 return jss.Serialize(CalendarEvents);
```

And I would rather used jquery to call webservices. And watch out for the d. prefix in asmx. webservices when consuming them with jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So can you also help with the reference issue? Also, I am not able to use JQuery for this as it is not allowed for now.

Comment: You can use the default asp.net ajax script library also. It works too, but I think jQuery has a smoother syntax when doing ajax calls (= less to write).

Comment: Or you can use pagemethods and then eliminate the use of webservices altogether. http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx